# Can someone help me stop this error I keep getting anytime the flush bar shows in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[FlushBar error [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGRab.png)

This error as shown in the image keeps coming up in the debug console anytime the flushbar plugin I’m using in my project shows shows information on the users screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the version solved the issue without changing any part of the code for me. use another_flushbar: `^1.10.5` . gotta fix this issue!
if that didn't work this might not be the best solution ever but you can use `overlay_support 1.0.5` which works very similar and just fine.